# Dynamic Aggregation of Dates

Tags: powerbi, time-series, grouping, binning, linegraph

I am trying to build a time series, but when a large date range is selected, I get a very noisy line graph.
I want to to aggregate the data when a large date range is selected BUT still show unaggregated data when a small date range is selected.

Creating a Group is essentially what I am looking to do BUT only for large date ranges.
I do not want the user to have to manually manipulate anything but the date range.
Maybe I am missing an inherent function of the Line Chart?

How do I accomplish this?

Short Date Range (Good):
[image: Short Date Range (Good)]

Long Date Range (Bad):

[image: Long Date Range (Bad)]

I attempted to chart the data without modifications and got a noisy graph. I attempted charting Groups but the groups do not change based on the filter and short date ranges lack clarity.